# Terminal does not find the installed Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

i have download and installed the Xcode 12.4 from apple site (not apple store) because I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and the latest Xcode version  right now requires at-least BigSur 11.0. I have also installed the latest Xcode command line tools.

[image: xcode command line tools]

But when i try to open my react native project in Xcode simulator from terminal using `npm run ios` it says,

"Xcode needs to be installed (don't worry, you won't have to use it), would you like to continue to the App Store? › (Y/n)"

[image]

By the way, I am a new mac user so, i don't know much about it yet. So, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try selecting your installed xcode version running: `xcode-select -s path/to/your/Xcode.app`. You may need to install command line tools again.

Answer (score 38):

My bad, i have not selected the installed command line tools in Xcode. If anybody got this issue then make sure you also select the installed command line tools. Simply open Xcode, go to preference -> locations -> command line tools.

Comment: I had the same issue on my fresh Big Sur install and this solved it for me, thank you!

Comment: Thanks! This worked when I had an issue with Expo go after a fresh update of xCode.

Answer (score 21):

If you're having this issue, running the command below in the terminal will also fix it for you.

```
    sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting this error while trying to run an app into the iOS simulator:

"**Xcode must be fully installed before you can continue. Continue to the App Store?**"

---

There are two things that needs to be checked before running an app into the simulator.

1. Command Line Tools
2. Agree to the Terms of Xcode

**1. Command Line Tools**

Open Xcode, go to settings → locations → select command line tools.

*Refer to the screenshots below.*

**2. Agree to the Terms of Xcode**

Run the below command in your terminal & you're ready to use simulator.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

*Screenshots:*
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Xcode
2. go to settings
3. go to locations tab
4. select an Xcode version in the select labeled "Command Line Tools"