# Expo client is not installing on Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I have been using this setup for almost half a year now and I upgraded the Expo SDK to 44 (erased all content and settings on the simulator). Ever since, the expo client won't install on the simulator.

Things I have tried:

- run expo client:install:ios
- uninstall and reinstall expo
- uninstall and reinstall watchman
- tried different simulators (15.0 that I used so far)
- creating a new blank expo project
- open the simulator first and then npm start
- I even did a complete MacBook reset (factory, needed to wipe anyway) and reinstalled following the expo documentation.

I read something about installing expo without sudo, but then it will throw errors and will simply not install.

New blank expo project infos:

Expo : 44.0.0
expo-cli: 5.0.3
react-native: 0.64.3

Hope someone knows the solution to this, I really want to get back programming.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: There is no error. Terminal just tells me it is done. It acts like it was a success.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037142/5871819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mercify said, sudo was indeed the problem.

For future reference: if installing expo without sudo throws an error, it is nessecary to change "the owner" of the folder "/usr/.../node_modules" to your user.
This post helps changing the owner.

[Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)

Expo is now installing on the Simulator.
Thanks to @Mercify.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Turns out using sudo when installing expo-cli is the issue. Run the following commands to resolve it.

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Then from your Mac's user's directory in a new terminal, run the following:

```
mkdir apps
cd apps
expo init app-name
```

Once this finishes, it should work just fine after running `npm start`.

Comment: thank you, I would love to try that, but without sudo it always responds with permission denied, even though I gave terminal full disk access in my macs system settings.